# iOS Webview App, How to open JSON Parse Push Notification in Webview?

Tags: ios, json, parse-platform, webview

I have a basic webview app working properly and receiving basic text push notifications from Parse.com, but cannot figure out how to get it to open a URL.

I want to send a JSON push notification from Parse.com as something like this and have it open up the specified URL in my webview app:

EDIT**  New issue I'm having now is I'm not able to open the URL in the webview if the app is in the background or in foreground.

Currently, if the app is in the background and you tap the notification it will just bring the app to the foreground but not reload the new URL.  And if the app is in the foreground, the notification is received as an alert and no action happens when you tap "OK".

```
{
"alert": "Push title goes here", 
"url": "http://www.google.com" 
}
```

In my **WebBrowserAppDelegate.m** I have this:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        [Parse setApplicationId:@"XXX"
                      clientKey:@"XXX"];

        // Register for Push Notitications
        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                                 categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    NSDictionary *notificationPayload = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    NSString *pushURL = [notificationPayload objectForKey:@"url"];

    if (notification) {
        NSDictionary *aDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: pushURL forKey:@"urlToLoad"];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LoadRequestFromAppDel" object:Nil userInfo:aDict];
    }

    return YES;
    }
     - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
        [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
        }
```

And in my **WebBrowserViewController.m** I have this:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSAssert(self.back, @"Unconnected IBOutlet 'back'");
        NSAssert(self.forward, @"Unconnected IBOutlet 'forward'");
        NSAssert(self.refresh, @"Unconnected IBOutlet 'refresh'");
        NSAssert(self.stop, @"Unconnected IBOutlet 'stop'");
        NSAssert(self.webView, @"Unconnected IBOutlet 'webView'");

        self.webView.delegate = self;
        self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com"];
        NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [self.webView loadRequest:request];
        [self updateButtons];
    }

- (void)LoadRequestFromAppDel: (NSNotification*)aNotif
{
    NSString *aStrUrl=[[aNotif userInfo] objectForKey:@"urlToLoad"];
    NSURL* pushurl = [NSURL URLWithString:aStrUrl];
    NSURLRequest* requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pushurl];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self updateButtons];
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you need to intercept the response from parse. I'll show you one sec.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you intercept a remote push using parse.com:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    NSDictionary *notificationPayload = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    NSString *productId = [notificationPayload objectForKey:@"p"];

    if (notification) {
    //this will only trigger when the app has been opend from a remote PUSH notification!!

        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)notification];
        _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

        _customRootViewController = [EZPUSHEXAMPLENavigationController new];
        [_customRootViewController setNavigationBarHidden:true];
        [self.window setRootViewController:_customRootViewController];

        if ([PFUser currentUser] == nil) {
            [self registerForNotifications:application launchOptions:launchOptions];
            EZPUSHEXAMPLEPreSplashViewController * splashScreen = [[EZPUSHEXAMPLEPreSplashViewController alloc] init];
            [_customRootViewController setViewControllers:@[splashScreen] animated:TRUE];
        } else {
            EZPUSHEXAMPLEPreSplashViewController * splashScreen = [[EZPUSHEXAMPLEPreSplashViewController alloc] init];
            EZPUSHEXAMPLECustomTabBarController * mvc = [[EZPUSHEXAMPLECustomTabBarController alloc] init];
            [mvc.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:TRUE];
            [mvc.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [(EZPUSHEXAMPLEFeedViewController*)[[[[mvc viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] setProductId:productId];
            [_customRootViewController setViewControllers:@[splashScreen, mvc] animated:TRUE];
     }
        return YES;
    } else {
        _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
        _customRootViewController = [EZPUSHEXAMPLENavigationController new];
        [_customRootViewController setNavigationBarHidden:true];
        [self.window setRootViewController:_customRootViewController];
        if ([PFUser currentUser] == nil) {
            [self registerForNotifications:application launchOptions:launchOptions];
            EZPUSHEXAMPLEPreSplashViewController * splashScreen = [[EZPUSHEXAMPLEPreSplashViewController alloc] init];
            [_customRootViewController setViewControllers:@[splashScreen] animated:TRUE];
        } else {
            EZPUSHEXAMPLEPreSplashViewController * splashScreen = [[EZPUSHEXAMPLEPreSplashViewController alloc] init];
            EZPUSHEXAMPLECustomTabBarController * mvc = [[EZPUSHEXAMPLECustomTabBarController alloc] init];
            [mvc.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:TRUE];
            [mvc.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [_customRootViewController setViewControllers:@[splashScreen, mvc] animated:TRUE];
        }
        return YES;
    }
}
```

In the example above, in your case, in the first part of the "if (notification)" trigger, you would initialize your custom web view controller and then present it or set it or push it, however you'd like, this is verified as working right now using Parse Cloud code triggers for push notification events when the APP IS COMPLETELY CLOSED BY THE USER. So, this means that this notification even will trigger on a fully closed app. I don't know if this will work when the app is in the background, but this will work when it's fully closed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Going to test this out right now, sorry if this is a dumb question, but I would just drop this in my WebBrowserAppDelegate.m underneath where I set my Parse ApplicationId and ClientKey?

Comment: basically, yeah, just the if/then portion and the declarations before the if/then portions, and then make sure you are "retriving the correct keys" from the push dictionary, in my case, "p" is a custom field in the dictionary that is pushed from Cloud Code.

Comment: And, then also, there's some pretty intense typecasting to method calls I'm using there. You shouldn't use methods like this in your instance, most likely, only because it's going to confuse the hell out of you more than likely right now, but the idea is that you send a custom object message string value in the userinfodictionary in the JSON push you send from Parse. You then intercept this message and look for your custom filed value, then do work or make changes to what you want your action to be based on this custom string value.

Comment: Got this working, but yep as you said it only works when the app is completely closed.  Does not open the URL when the app is open or in the background.  Any idea how to initialize the webview when open or in background?

Comment: Yep, i'll post a little later to give you a hand, it's not too much different from the above but just requires that you access methods outside this main method in appdelegate.

Comment: Thanks!! I've updated my code in OP with what I used to get it working while app is closed.

Comment: Just wanted to see if you would still be able to help me out here with opening the URL in webview when the app is open or in the background, thanks!